# How to fit a curve to data of an excel file, which contains NaN value

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm a beginner in python. I have an excel file. This excel file shows the daily value of a parameter. This excel file contained data for four years. Some values are `NaN`. This a sample of my excel file.

```
Date     f11
0        0.002
1        0.004
2          -
.
.
.
1625       -
1626    -0.001
1627    -0.0013
```

I want to find a fitted curve to `f11` data by a model. This is my code.

```
df =pd.read_excel ('final-all-filters.xlsx')
x = df['Date']
y = df['f11'].dropna(how='all', axis=0)
def model(x, b, m, c, d, f, g, h, i):
    return b+m*x+ c*np.sin(x/180)+d*np.cos(x/180)+h*np.sin(x/180)+i*np.cos(x/180)+ f/g * np.exp (681-x)* np.heaviside(x-681, 681)

popt,pcov = curve_fit (model, x, y, p0=[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 ], maxfev = 10000)
print (popt)
```

When I run this code I face the error of

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1639,) (1632,)
```

I should mention that when I fill the `NaN` cells with a random value the model works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are only dropping the `NaN` from the y-values.
You should drop the afflicted rows from the Dataframe first, and then create the series for the `x` and `y` values.

Try:

```
fixed = df.dropna()
x = fixed['Date']
y = fixed['f11']
def model(x, b, m, c, d, f, g, h, i):
    return b+m*x+ c*np.sin(x/180)+d*np.cos(x/180)+h*np.sin(x/180)+i*np.cos(x/180)+ f/g * np.exp (681-x)* np.heaviside(x-681, 681)

popt,pcov = curve_fit (model, x, y, p0=[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 ], maxfev = 10000)
print (popt)
```

**Edit**:

Once you have created the model from the data without the `NaN`s, you can use it to fill in the missing data.

Comment: I don't want to drop the corresponding X value. The model should find a value for NaN cells.

Comment: You can do that *after* creating the model from the cleaned data. I assumed that was obvious.

Answer (score -1):

You've dropped NaNs from Y but you didn't drop cresponding indexes from X. You have to do this to get model running.

Comment: I don't want to drop the corresponding X value. The model should find a value for NaN cells.

Comment: If you want to find a value to replace NaN try imputation

Comment: So If you don't want to drop values, you should look on this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html